# New VB Project from Existing Project Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have the project files for a program that was compiled in Visual Basic. 
The extensions are:

```
.cls
.frm
.frx
.bas
.SCC
.vbp
.vbw
```

Currently the files are in a .zip
How do I import these into a new project to modify the code and recompile it myself?

Comment: im not sure i understand. I believe what I have are the saved project/solution files. Im trying to import/open them so I can view the code. Let me rephase my question.

Comment: I see a .scc file. So go to your Source code control system and get the latest version of the code into your workspace.

Comment: Im actually new to VB. Where can I find the source code control system? Argh..I thought it would be sa easy as importing into Android SDK..

Comment: Android? That's a completely different system.

Comment: Yes It is. I imported the .vbp and it looks like its importing the rest of the files. Thank you, Mitch.